# Box overflow with 1000+ answer upvotes on User page

Tags: bug, status-completed, answers, up-votes, profile-page

In light of [bobince](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18936/bobince) getting 1000+ votes for his [minor HTML/regexp conniption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454), I do believe his answer has *escaped the confinement of its box*.  Everyone run for your lives!

[image]

Comment: I do believe someone has trumped Welbog.

Comment: Quoth the Taco Bell dog : "Uh Oh, I think I need a bigger box!"

Comment: Anyway, I don't see a problem in IE7. (Hey, I don't get to say *that* often!)

Comment: For reference, the screenshot was taken in Firefox 3.5.5

Comment: making the box bigger was not even one of the suggestions! Unless you count the Taco Bell dog...

Answer (score 6):

If the `font-size` is changed to `70%` it looks fine too:

[image with freehand circle http://john.cognitivedelay.com/images/so-votecount.png](http://john.cognitivedelay.com/images/so-votecount.png)

Comment: Is that a challenge to a free-handed-circle duel?

Comment: Ha, it's more a "freehand spiral" duel

Answer (score 4):

Bob's got a cookie monster avatar.  It's a tragedy that this is not included in the screeshots.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Easy solution. Should be written as "1k"

Comment: Disagree, unless there's an easy way to see the exact vote total as well. I think if you earned that many votes for a post, you're likely to want to know just what the exact final score turns out to be.

Comment: Well, you should be able to see the vote count beside the post itself. I think using a "K" makes it look much more unique!

Comment: You could just make the actual number appear as a tooltip with "1.0k" in the box.

Comment: besides in a few days bobince's cuthulu regex-html answer will need to be "1.0m"

Answer (score 1):

Its just *barely* inside the box with the latest version of Opera.

Comment: that's because Opera is rendering all the fonts smaller than every other browser (Safari, Chrome, IE, Firefox). Why? Who knows..

Answer (score 0):

Makes me wish we could favorite answers.

Comment: Or just annotate favorited questions.