# Small layout glitch on user home page if an answer has over 1k votes

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Box overflow with 1000+ answer upvotes on User page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29922/box-overflow-with-1000-answer-upvotes-on-user-page)

There is a small layout glitch on user home page if an answer has more than 1000 votes. The vote count will not fit the allocated box.

For example see the first answer on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18936/bobince).

This affects at least Chrome and Firefox 3.5 with Vista.

Comment: dupe de dupe de dupe... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29922/box-overflow-with-1000-answer-upvotes-on-user-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confimerd. Firefox 3.5.5 on Windows XP Pro 32
[image]